# Changing Data Structure in Data Table

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I want to change the structure of my DataTable. My datatable shows data in following format:-
[image]

I pivoted my datatable, using following code.

```
    public DataTable PivotTable(DataTable source)
{
    DataTable dest = new DataTable("Pivoted" + source.TableName);
    dest.Columns.Add(" ");
    foreach (DataRow r in source.Rows)
        dest.Columns.Add(r[0].ToString());
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        dest.Rows.Add(dest.NewRow());
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < dest.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < dest.Columns.Count; c++)
        {
            if (c == 0)
                dest.Rows[r][0] = source.Columns[r + 1].ColumnName;
            else
                dest.Rows[r][c] = source.Rows[c - 1][r + 1];
        }
    }
    dest.AcceptChanges();
    return dest;
}
```

After pivoting my Datatable shows record in following format:-

[image]

But I need result in following format:-
[image]

That is if there are 1 Sector it should show till 1 stop, if there are 3 Sector then it should show till 3 stop. It should increase or decrease automatically.

Please help me with the code.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to transform the data at the datastore level?

Comment: the data is coming from XML, from XML I am creating Data Table.